# Word Interop 2007 silent printing issue

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I am using:

- Office 2007
- VC# Express 2010
- 1x Citrix virtual XP network environment accessed through Windows 7 laptop host
- 1x printer set to output to .prn in a given network-mapped drive

I am using C# and Word Interop to silently print a given set of files automatically.  The application scans an input folder every 10 minutes for .doc / .docx files only, and inputs their path&filename into a list.  Foreach found file, attempt to print via the following code:

```
public static Boolean PrintFoundFiles(List<string> foundFiles)
    {
        successful = false;
        foreach (string file in foundFiles)
        {
            object fileAndPath = file;              //declare my objects here, since methods want an object passed
            object boolTrue = true;                 //
            object boolFalse = false;               //
            object output = FormatOutputName(file); //
            object missing = System.Type.Missing;   //
            object copies = "1";                    //
            object pages = "";                      //
            object items = Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent; //
            object range = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;    //
            object pageType = Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;    //

            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application(); //open word application
            wordApp.Visible = false; //invisible
            Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileAndPath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing); //opens the word document into application behind the scenes
            doc.Activate(); //activates document, else when I print the system will throw an exception
            wordApp.ActivePrinter = "my printer name"; //Specify printer I will print from
            doc.PrintOut(ref boolTrue, ref boolFalse, ref range, ref output, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref boolTrue, ref boolTrue,
                ref missing, ref boolFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            doc.Close(SaveChanges: false);
            doc = null;
            ((Word._Application)wordApp).Quit(SaveChanges: false); //kill word process the right way
            wordApp = null; //reset to null
            successful = true;
        }
        return successful;
    }
```

After I receive the true boolean of "successful", I will back up the file automatically in a backup folder, delete it in the input folder, and look for the .prn in the output folder (it just sits here for processing later).

If I don't provide an output (see ref output on doc.PrintOut()), the output directory doesn't get updated or printed to at all.  If I DO provide an output, the .prn is created, though it is a 0kb empty file.

The printer is set up as the default printer, and it has been configured to automatically output to said output folder.  If I open Word manually with the same file I'm trying to automatically print from, hit print, it will create a 6kb .prn file in the output directory without having to hit anything other than CTRL + P, OK.

I'm fairly confident the file is being opened OK via "Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open()" because I did a doc.FullName and got the full path of the input word document in question.  I just cannot for the life of me get the .prn to output correctly to the output folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I start my word (2010) and record a macro of me pressing Ctrl+P and hitting print - I'm getting

```
Application.PrintOut fileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
    wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
    wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
    PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
    PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

Change your PrintOut to reflect what Word did and see if it solves your issue.

There's no reason to be "fairly confident", just remove

```
wordApp.Visible = false
```

Debug your program and make certain it's OK.

Comment: Your second suggestion was the most useful.  I made my program visible for debugging purposes, and saw that the program quit right after the print method.  I put a `Thread.Sleep(5000);` in between the print method and the quit method, and of course it worked fine.

What a silly mistake.  Ah well, thank you.  



TIL (yet again) assumptions don't work in programming.